# What updates iTunes?

Tags: windows-7, itunes

I like iTunes 10, so I keep an installer around.

Unfortunately, iTunes has lately taken to updating itself to version 11 without even asking anymore, meaning every couple of days I start it up to find I have to uninstall it, restore the music library from backup, and re-install version 10.

I have uninstalled Apple Software Update, as well as denying this and iTunes access to the internet with my firewall.

Yet, it still manages to update.

**What executable is responsible for updating iTunes on Windows?**

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you don't want to use iTunes 11?

Comment: Go to **Help > Run Diagnostics**, select only the **Network connectivity tests** option and follow the guided procedure. When done, post here the diagnostic output.

Comment: In iTunes **Edit > Preferences > General tab > uncheck "Check for new software updates automatically"**

Comment: @Richard, I don't like the interface. I use iTunes 10 as an MP3 player only, and have done for a long time. It does everything I want it to. I know where everything is. It's never crashed. I also think it looks nicer than iTunes 11.
Some apps yes, esp. new ones, that do complicated things like 3d modelling or desktop publishing, provide significant productivity gains with UI and stability improvements in each update.
iTunes 10 though does one thing. Its done that thing perfectly for what feels 10 years, and will continue to do so for another 10... 
if only I can keep Apple away from it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Apple Software Updater does the updating of your applications according to your preferences.

The Apple Updater is controlled by a Scheduled Task in Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Scheduled Tasks

Comment: The scheduled task you're referring to is called `AppleSoftwareUpdate`, which starts the `SoftwareUpdate.exe` application with the `-task` parameter. As the OP has stated, however, **Apple Software Update** is not installed any more, and that means the task is gone.

Comment: I think this is it. I *definitely* uninstalled Apple Software Update. Twice. And it somehow came back. The update check box is unchecked in iTunes, but not in Apple Software Update. I have unchecked it in ASU. I have also deleted the EXE and renamed one of the DLLs to SoftwareUpdate.exe to try and flummox whatever it was that was re-installing it...

Comment: (I've also set Deny on my fake exe for every user. Whatever's re-installing it can get around my firewall, can get around the 'read-only' flag I put on the iTunes install dir, but it surely isn't smart enough to change permissions! I hope.)

Comment: (To update, now that ASU has been disabled (by replacing the exe with a dummy and then locking all the users out of it) iTunes has been safe for two weeks.)